# Is it possible to have an automatic email for reviews/ratings of application on Google Play?

Tags: android, email, console, rating-system

I have just created my first android game for my final year project in University! Since I have published it I have had a couple of reviews and ratings.

Is it possible to set up an automatic email that will post, once a review or rating has been marked on the app!

I am new to the Google play developer console so I may have missed this option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a setting to do that within the Developer Console. And AFAIK there is still no official API for the developer console, so there would be no legit way to set one up yourself. You just have to keep checking in on it if you want to know when there are new reviews.